# How to compare user input with db password when using PHP's sha256 hash method?

Tags: php, hash, sha256

Say I set a new users password like this:

```
$salt = random_string(40) // some method that spits out a random
                          // 40 alpha-numeric character string

$password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt);
```

How do I then compare the users input to his hashed db password when he wants to log in?

Comment: Do the same thing again?  If you know how to compute the hash for password, take user input and re-compute hash and then compare to hash stored in some database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At login time,

1. Fetch the password hash and the salt you stored in the database at registration time (using the account name, or email-address)
2. Hash the provided password with the same method and the same salt
3. Compare the hash you get with the hash you stored. If they are the same, the password matches.

The key here is to store the salt.

Comment: But won't storing the salt contradict it's purpose?

Comment: The salt will just make it harder to check if two people have the same password. If you want better protection against brute-force attacks if your database is seized, I recommend using something slower (like bcrypt) to make bruteforcing way too long.

Comment: Would blowfish encryption be overkill for a site with a couple of thousand users?

Comment: Well, phpass is very simple to use, lightweight, and it's better to be safe than sorry – especially w.r.t user passwords. It even takes care of the salting part automatically.

Comment: the purpose of the salt is to stop rainbow table attacks, storing it is not a problem, as recreating a rainbow table with your salt is impracticable for an attacker, and if they had the table with the salt, then all the data is already compromised.

Answer (score 1):

having stored the salt, you apply the same algorithm to what the user posts and compare the results with the stored password.